# Global variable ( orientation ) in objective C

Tags: ios

I am a somewhat new comer to xcode coming from .NET and java, I am working with a lot of xibs that are loaded through code, and working on different device orientations. 
I am noticing through my code that in each xib I need to fork some code based on orientation, ( mainly portrait VS landscape ) on therefore use this line a lot :

```
       UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

my question is: how can I make this a global variable ( don't wanna use the word static here. )
but some where in my multi xib large project where I can do this :

```
   -(UIInterfaceOrientation)currentOrientation {
return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

}

That are the best practices for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hm. This is not related to Xcode. You could as well use any other IDE for writing Objective-C code.

Comment: **1.** `#define GlobalOrientation [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`, **2.** `static inline UIInterfaceOrientation GlobalOrientation() { return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]; }` etc...